# Trying to adding cookie consent, I keep getting redirected to another website

Tags: html, cookies

I found some good tutorials in adding cookies in my website:

https://knowledgebase.webydo.com/en/articles/1942483-how-do-i-add-a-cookie-consent-to-my-website
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8R4UP4f1cQQ&t=276s

They explain well, and I would like to follow these guides because all other cookie tutorials are with wordpress and other web creating sites, which mine is not.

If I try to go to their link: https://cookieconsent.insites.com/download I get annoyingly redirected to https://www.osano.com/. Why is this the case? the tutorials are fairly recent and there is no indication that osano took over.

Comment: It does look like osano is the parent: [Github](https://github.com/osano/cookieconsent) "Cookie Consent by Osano". It says that that tutorial was updated a week ago, but I don't see a indication of when it was written originally.

Comment: That tutorial page has a feedback mechanism at the bottom. Maybe alert them that the links are out of date.